# Remove lines from a file that begin with and do not end with in bash

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have read many sed examples on how to remove lines beginning with a specific character or character set which is not challenging but I cannot seem to crack this one. I want to remove all lines in a file that begin with the letter "i" and DO NOT end with ".conf".

The following is a list example:

```
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
include /usr/local/cho
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
i
incl
```

The 3 lines that need to be removed in the above example are:

```
include /usr/local/cho
i
incl
```

They are incomplete and cannot be in there.

I have tried a few variations of examples I have seen on StackExchange and StackOverflow as well as various other forums but I cannot seem to get it right. Here is what I've tried:

```
sed -i '/^i.*[^\.conf]$/d' /usr/local/choops/users/main.conf

sed -i '/^i.\*\[^\\.conf\]$/d' /usr/local/choops/users/main.conf

sed -i '/^i.*[^.conf]$/d' /usr/local/choops/users/main.conf
```

Where main.conf is the file that lists a set of .conf files as show above. I didn't think this one would be too complicated but none of these commands seem to work for me. I built the commands from various sources and understanding of sed. Any help would be appreciated, I'm stumped.

The following did the opposite of what I want but I guess that's an easy one:

```
sed -i 's/i.*.conf//' main.conf
```

Comment: You should have included some lines that do not start with `i` in your sample input/output so we could see (and test with) that aspect of your requirements. Since you didn't, you're getting some answers that would delete any line that doesn't start with `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two clauses that must both be satisfied ("starts with i", "doesn't end with .conf"). For a line to be excluded from the output, each clause needs to be tested separately and then AND-ed together.

Sample input (with extra lines not beginning with "i" added):

```
$ cat input.txt 
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
this line doesn't begin with i
include /usr/local/cho
this line doesn't begin with i but does end in .conf
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
i
incl
```

with `perl`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless (/^i/ && ! /\.conf$/)' input.txt 
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
this line doesn't begin with i
this line doesn't begin with i but does end in .conf
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
```

with `sed`:

```
$ sed -ne '/^i/ {/\.conf$/!d;};p' input.txt 
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
this line doesn't begin with i
this line doesn't begin with i but does end in .conf
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
```

Alternatively (probably better), as @seshoumara suggests:

```
sed -e '/^i/ {/\.conf$/!d;}' input.txt
```

All three versions delete the unwanted lines from the output, printing everything else.

Comment: sed -i '/^i/ {/\.conf$/!d};' input.txt  did it. I wanted to remove the lines not only show them. Thank you for showing me how.

Comment: both the perl and sed versions do it.  and both have a `-i` option for "in-place edit" of the original file.

Comment: It clears the data from the line but does not backspace/remove the line. Can sed doe this?

Comment: Just remove -n and the explicit printing, it will do the printing automatically. The d command isn't just clear pattern space, it immediately starts next cycle, so no empty line will be printed.

Comment: @robetus i don't understand your question.  Both versions remove the unwanted lines from the output, - they don't "clear data from the line", they **delete** unwanted lines.  As would sesoumara's suggested change.

Comment: Upon further examination, it does remove the line completely. My mistake. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @kusalananda why add the semi-colons? is there some version of sed where `{}` blocks don't work without a final `;` ?  It works without them for GNU and busybox sed - I don't have easy access to other versions to test.

Comment: `sed` on at least macOS and FreeBSD require those semi-colons.

Comment: I'll have to fire up my freebsd vm to test with in future, that's mostly what I made it for.

Comment: Forgot to say that OpenBSD also needs the semi-colon, but I can't say anything about NetBSD right now. Without the semi-colon you get the error `extra characters at the end of d command`. I didn't do anything about the other answer here as it additionally used `-i` in a way incompatible with `sed` on some of these systems, and it was just going to be too intrusive. Your answer was just a 2-character enhancement.

Comment: fair enough. btw, i wasn't complaining about your edit, i just wanted to know the reason.  if i didn't like the edit or found the reason insufficient, i would have just rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have two conditionals, if line starts with 'i' and on true if line doesn't end with '.conf'. Instead of doing it in one search, do it in two.

```
sed -i '/^i/{/\.conf$/!d}' /usr/local/choops/users/main.conf
```

Alternatively, if you have something that does the opposite, just negate it.

```
sed -i '/^i.*\.conf$/!d' /usr/local/choops/users/main.conf
```

Notice that the dot needs escaped, otherwise it is a regex meaning any character.

The '[^abc]' regex you tried actually represents: a single character that is not 'a', not 'b', nor 'c'. Could be 'j' or 'z'. Whatever that regex will match, it is still a single character. Lastly, the characters in '[]' or '[^]' can't have any regex meaning, just a list of literal characters, so '.' will always mean dot, no need to escape it. But in // or s/// you want it escaped, for your case.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove all lines in a file that begin with the letter "i" and DO NOT end with ".conf"

- Let `A` denote "*begin with the letter `i`*"
- Let `B` denote "*end with `.conf`*"

Using [Boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we can say that you want to delete lines matching the condition "A and not B":

```
A . B'
```

Furthermore we can rewrite this as "the negation of { not A, or B }":

```
( A' + B'' )' = ( A' + B )'
```

Using `grep` we can invert this to *keep* (rather than removing) lines matching the expression, so:

```
( A' + B )
```

In code this then becomes,

```
grep -E '^[^i]|\.conf$'
```

Although actually we also need to account for lines that don't start with any character at all (ie they are blank),

```
grep -E '^[^i]|\.conf$|^$'
```

Using your example file you get to keep these lines:

```
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
```

The usual rules apply for in-place editing (it's smoke and mirrors), so we apply that ourselves

```
grep ... file >file.tmp &&
    mv -f -- file.tmp file
rm -f -- file.tmp
```

Comment: It's not possible with sed? I don't want remove and recreate a file.

Comment: Worth a shot but didn't work: sed -i '/^[^i]|.conf$|^$/d'

Comment: Empty lines don't start with 'i', so OP has no deletion condition for them. I understand the intention, but maybe the OP didn't want it.

Comment: @robetus of course it's possible with `sed`. I chose to use `grep`. It achieves your requirement

Comment: @seshoumara empty lines don't satisfy the removal conditions stated by the OP so we keep them

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk we can identify the lines you want to delete by simply translating your stated matching requirement, `begin with the letter "i" and DO NOT end with ".conf"`, to code:

```
$ awk '/^i/ && !/\.conf$/' file
include /usr/local/cho
i
incl
```

then trivially negate that condition to get the lines you want to keep:

```
$ awk '!(/^i/ && !/\.conf$/)' file
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
```

which, if you prefer, can be abbreviated by [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to:

```
$ awk '!/^i/ || /\.conf$/' file
include /usr/local/choops/users/2488.conf
include /usr/local/choops/users/2492.conf
```